# integrate gulp and bower with django for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, django, gulp

I am new in django and I try configure angularjs template with django. Angularjs template uses gulp configration. So anyone please tell me that how I configure gulp with django to run Angularjs template ? Plaese suggest me tutorial or steps for this.

Comment: You do not try to run angular template in django. You need to write rest api in django app to communicate with angular app

Comment: I have to configure angularjs app with django server. I already have rest api on another django server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Angular templates directly in django.

You can use something like [Webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) to integrate both.

In the end you have a simple template that outputs

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<div id="myapp"></div>
render_bundle 'myangularapp'
```

The Angular application is handled on the webpack side of things. [This might help](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/).